# 'View controller' does not conform to protocol 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am working on an app that connects to a bluetooth module that I am using. This is my first time using Swift and I am not familiar with the syntax and what not. How would I go about fixing this error? Thank you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var device: CBPeripheral!
    let DEVICE_NAME = "name"
    let DEVICE_SERVICE_UUID = "20510dfs1-3a03-0dab-b24f-07dfad6ef352"
    let DEVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "00510001-3a03-0dab-b24f-07dfad6ef352"
    let RESTORE_IDENTIFIER = "restoreKeyForDevice"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:RESTORE_IDENTIFIER])
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually implement the delegate methods.

Comment: You have to implement protocols mentioned https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate